# Migrating DNS Service for an Existing Domain to Amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have read all the information about my question in this article ([Amazon Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html)). Actually I have a domain .net bought in Amazon working correctly but I need migrate a .ly domain to route my request to my Elastic Beanstalk (like .net domain).

I have requested the *zone file* like say in the article:

> If you can get a zone file from your current DNS service provider, you
>   can import your existing DNS configuration into your Amazon Route 53
>   hosted zone, which greatly simplifies the process of creating resource
>   record sets. Try asking customer support for your current DNS service
>   provider how to get a zone file or a records list.

This is my *zone file* (domain is not the real name, is just a example):

```
; Zone file for domain.ly
$TTL 14400
domain.ly.  86400   IN  SOA dns1.onlydomains.net.   support.libyaonline.com.    (
2014120106 ;Serial Number
86400 ;refresh
7200 ;retry
3600000 ;expire
86400 ;minimum
)
domain.ly.  86400   IN  NS  dns1.onlydomains.net.
domain.ly.  86400   IN  NS  dns3.onlydomains.net.
domain.ly.  14400   IN  A   96.127.***.54
localhost   14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
www 14400   IN  CNAME   domain-env.elasticbeanstalk.com.
```

I have imported it and I have read all the article but and I don't understand what I need to do in the next steps.

I don't know what to do with de NS and SOA... Do I need contact with the domain .ly support again?

**Some Important Details:**

- The IP 96.127.###.54 is not the IP of my Elastic BeanStalk, I have other IP (like this 54.77.###.42)
- The CNAME domain-env.elasticbeanstalk.com is not the correct. I changed it for newelastic-domain.elasticbeanstalk.com (and it's working fine with the .net domain)

This is the last step, that I don't understand...  ([Updating Your Registrar's Name Servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html#Step_UpdateRegistrar))

Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to do, and it looks like you did one.

You created the domain records in route 53, and told route 53 where to route everything when the DNS requests come in for that domain.

Unfortunately, you have not yet told the world who to ask when they have a question about your domain  - that is what the link your provided is telling you to do. You need to go to your domain registrar (the place where you registered the domain), and tell it to use route53 to manage your DNS, i.e. specifiy the Custom DNS servers that will become the defintive source for who to ask - you get those 4 custom name servers from amazon route 53 panel, they would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Chances are you should be able to login to your account with them, and do it yourself .

Comment: I don't have this option :(

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/elmzbw6242q9f5w/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-12-29%20a%20las%2019.41.39.png?dl=0 

Hi! Is this option where I need to change it? I get a message that says me that I can't change manually. Regards.

Comment: Thats it, get the info from aws route 53 and put them in there. It will take a few hours to propagate usually.

Comment: Ok, I have written a ticket support to change it, thank you so much and Happy New Year ;)